# HTML письма - задать ширину 100% для изображения в MS Outlook

Tags: html, css, email

В Outlook 2010 (windows outlook v. 14.0.71815000) изображение не растягивается на 100% ширины контейнера.

Ширина контейнера для всего контента письма - 600рх. Верстка табличная, все стили прописаны инлайн. Для изображения стили такие:

```
<img src=".." width="600" style="display: block; border: 0px; outline: none; width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 600px;">
```

Как растянуть картинку на всю ширину контейнера?

Comment: попробуйте добавить в head добавить - <!--[if gte mso 7]><xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->

Comment: @soledar10 к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Попробуй вместо `100%`  `100vw`

Answer (score 1):

Outlook не поддерживает `max-width` - [www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/max-width/](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/max-width/)

Попробуйте задавать `width: 600px;`:

```html
<table border-spacing="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="600" height="400" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-spacing: 0; background: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tbody>
      <!-- Изображение большего размера -->
      <tr> 
        <td align="center">          
          <img src="http://8-themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Animals_Beasts_Prickly_hedgehog_033791_.jpg" width="600" border="0" align="center" style="width: 600px;">
        </td> 
      </tr>
      
      <!-- Изображение меньшего размера -->
      <tr> 
        <td align="center">          
          <img src="http://dogtowndogtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/300x300-061-e1340955308953.jpg" width="600" border="0" align="center" style="width: 600px;">
        </td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: спасибо, но такое решение не подходит, т.к. письмо верстается не только для outlook. важно чтобы изображение адаптировалось под различне девайсы.

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, если "Ширина контейнера для всего контента письма - 600рх." то адаптироваться не будет.